# Is $\sup(A ) = 1$, $\;\inf(A) = -1 $? Choose the correct option

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let  $A = \bigl\{ t \sin (\frac {1}{t})\mid t \in (0, \frac{2}{\pi})\bigr\}$. Which of the following statement are true?

$1).$ $\sup(A) < \frac{2}{\pi} +\frac {1}{n\pi} $ for all $n \ge 1$

$2)$ $\inf(A) > \frac{-2}{3\pi} - \frac{1}{n\pi}$  for all $n \ge 1 $

$3)$ $\sup(A ) = 1$

$4)$ $\inf(A) = -1 $

**My attempts:**

I know  that $-1 \le t \sin (\frac {1}{t}) \le 1$, so  option 3 and option 4 is the correct answer.

Is it true or false?

Comment: `I know  that` $-1 \le t \sin (\frac {1}{t}) \le 1$. How do you know that?

Comment: see $ sin \frac {1}{t}  \le 1 $ as $sint \le  1$

Comment: Yes, but there's a factor of $t$ too.

Comment: @Shaun..can u help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since
$$-1 \leq \sin(x) \leq 1$$
for any real $x$, it follows that
$$-1 \leq \sin \Big(\dfrac{1}{x}\Big) \leq 1$$
for any real $x$, and it can be shown that 
$$-x \leq x\sin \Big(\dfrac{1}{x}\Big) \leq x$$
for any positive real $x$.

Since the values of $t$ are between $0$ and $\dfrac{2}{\pi}$, the values of
$$t\sin \Big(\dfrac{1}{t}\Big)$$
must be between $-\dfrac{2}{\pi}$ and $\dfrac{2}{\pi}$, which are around $\pm 0.6366$ and thus the least upper bound and greatest lower bound could not be $1$ and $-1$, they have to be at least $\dfrac{2}{\pi}$ and $-\dfrac{2}{\pi}$.

Since $\sup(A) \leq \dfrac{2}{\pi}$, number 1 is clearly true as $\dfrac{1}{n\pi}$ is strictly positive.

Statement 2 however is false. The minimum value of
$$t\sin \Big(\dfrac{1}{t}\Big)$$
is around $-0.21723$ which can be found using a method of numerical approximation, or some graphing software, I used desmos. The value of $-\dfrac{2}{3\pi}$ is around $-0.21221$ meaning that at some point the term $-\dfrac{1}{n\pi}$ would get small enough to make $-\dfrac{2}{3\pi} - \dfrac{1}{n\pi}$ as a whole greater than $\inf(A)$ which turned out to be just less than $-\dfrac{2}{3\pi}$. The value of $n$ which makes $-\dfrac{1}{n\pi}$ just big enough to make the statement
$$\inf(A) > -\dfrac{2}{3\pi} - \dfrac{1}{n\pi}$$
false is $64$, meaning
$$\inf(A) < -\dfrac{2}{3\pi} - \dfrac{1}{n\pi} \ \textrm{when} \ n \geq 64$$

Comment: thanks  u vincente

Answer (score 1):

The graph is a wave which dies off as $t$ approaches to $0$ from the right.

The supremum is the limit as $t$ approaches to the right end, $$t=2/\pi$$ and the supremum  is $$2/ \pi $$

The infimum is attained at the local minimum closet to the  right end which is at $t=0.2254769$ and the infimum is $y=-0.2172336$

Thus the options $(1)$ and $(2)$ are correct.

Comment: thanks u MoRiazi kermani